# Spark saving to Cassandra with TTL

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, connector, ttl

I am using Spark-Cassandra connector 1.1.0 with Cassandra 2.0.12.

I write RDDs to Cassandra via the saveToCassandra() Java API method.

Is there a way to set the TTL property of the persisted records with the connector?

Thanks,

Shai

Comment: For newer versions this is the documentation: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md#specifying-ttl-and-writetime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it doesn't seem like there is a way to do this (that I know of) with version 1.1.0 of the connector.  There is a way in 1.2.0-alpha3 however.

[`saveToCassandra()`](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/v1.2.0-alpha3/spark-cassandra-connector-java/src/main/java/com/datastax/spark/connector/japi/RDDAndDStreamCommonJavaFunctions.java#L52-L55) is a wrapper over WriterBuilder which has a [`withTTL`](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/v1.2.0-alpha3/spark-cassandra-connector-java/src/main/java/com/datastax/spark/connector/japi/RDDAndDStreamCommonJavaFunctions.java#L377-L379) method.  Instead of using `saveToCassandra` you could use `writerBuilder(keyspace,table,rowWriter).withTTL(seconds).saveToCassandra()`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can do.
Just set spark config key "**spark.cassandra.output.ttl**" .while creating sparkConf  Object.

**Note: Value should be in second**